# How to add values dynamically in combobox?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Here is HTML code, I'm using to load values dynamically

```
<select name="type" id="type" style="width: 200px;" onChange="settype();">
<option value="Education">Education</option>
<option value="Hospital">Hospital</option>
<option value="Marriage">Marriage</option>      
</select> 
<select name="subtype" id="subtype" style="width: 200px;"></select>
```

here values are added dynamically according to the  first combo box value

```
function settype() {            
        var hospital = new Array("Govt", "Private Hospital");
        var marriage = new Array("Marriage Hall", "Temple", "Resorts");
        var education = new Array("School", "College", "univercity");

        var select_Register_For = document.getElementById(type);
        var select_type = document.getElementById(subtype);
        var selected_sport = select_Register_For.options[select_Register_For.selectedIndex].value; 

          if (selected_sport === "Education") {
            for (var i = 0; i < education.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = education[i].value;
                option.value = education[i].value;
                select_type.add(option,0);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT YOUR QUESTIONS HERE. It makes them more difficult to read, it's rather annoying, and it won't get you help any faster. There are Shift keys on both sides of the keyboard to make them easy to reach, because properly cased text is more readable and understandable. Please use them. (It's also pretty rude to SHOUT at people you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem**.)

Answer (score 1):

Some of thinks that might cause issue.

- use `document.getElementById("type")` instead of `document.getElementById(type)` and same for `subtype` as well.
- use `education[i]` instead of `education[i].value` to get the value from array at index i.

Here is the function with some modification:

```
function settype() {
    var hospital = new Array("Govt", "Private Hospital");
    var marriage = new Array("Marriage Hall", "Temple", "Resorts");
    var education = new Array("School", "College", "univercity");

    var select_Register_For = document.getElementById("type");
    var select_type = document.getElementById("subtype");
    var selected_sport = select_Register_For.options[select_Register_For.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selected_sport === "Education") {
        for ( var i = 0; i < education.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = education[i];
            option.value = education[i];
            select_type.add(option, 0);
        }
    }
};
```